# Marketing Cloud License Expiry Information

Tags: marketing-cloud, licenses, userlicense

We can check current Salesforce CRM Licenses expiry date under Company information but where to check for Marketing Cloud Expiry date.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Admin - Account Settings - Subscription Details, you should see the start and end dates

[image]